# how to change a file sort in linux file system?

Tags: php, linux

what I want is control a file sort when I use php "readdir()" function in the linux system . 
In my case , it has so many files in the folder "A" , and readdir(A) will return:

```
3.txt
1.txt 
2.txt
2.xls
```

...
But I want it returns not as create time order,or more accurately the sequence of nodes in the linux file system, that's if I want to prior to returning "2.txt" such as :

```
2.txt 
3.txt
1.txt
2.xls
```

,how should I do ? php or linux command can do it?
thanks

[image]

Comment: This is not possible in a direct manner, simply because there is nothing like a sort order in a file system. The _result set_ can be ordered, sure. That is done in `cli` utilities by additional run time options. In php you can simply sort an array of file system folder entries to your liking. But there is no "global sorting mode" or similar.

Comment: just put the output into array and sort it whatever you want afterwards.

Comment: ok,thanks ,I know the method to pick up by array , I just want to know whether it is possible be changed the attribute ,such as touch(2.txt) ,it is done

Answer (score 0):

You can either exec a "ls" with the -S (--sort) parameter and then get the output, process it and use it (personally I think it is not that good solution) or you can use php built in tools: 
- scandir returns linear data structure (array) which is sortable by name (the second parameter is the sort type).... you can extend by building a more complex array by getting each file's modified timestamp, size or whatever and sort by those...

I usually prefer to rely on the input but in most cases you should adapt a common input based on your needs.

Comment: ok,thanks,It seems I am wrong,not only want to continue to use readdir() but also attempt to modify the node of linux filesystem, It is impossible, at least php function or linux command can not , thank you for your "ls -s",for the moment I would not to replace  the get list method . thanks :)